# Direction of correlation

Tags: correlation, pearson-r, psychometrics, psychology

There are two interdependent variables - experience and fun. Using a correlation, we can only say how fun and experience are related, and the strength of the relationship. My question is how do I check if (i) fun is influencing experience or (ii) experience is affecting fun? I am not clear how should the directional arrow be indicated, using the Pearson Correlation.

Comment: I think there might be some answer about this using Wilk's lambda. Have you considered looking into significance tests?

Comment: Using only Pearson correlation, you cannot come to any conclusions regarding the direction of the dependency. If you were to have measurements across time, then you might be able to use something like [Granger causality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Granger_causality).

Comment: This isn't very good question because ot does not elaborate whether a statistical (technical), methodological or philosophical response is expected.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe that a Pearson correlation is not capable of telling you which 'direction' the relationship is.

A Pearson correlation is essentially looking for the tendency of one variable to vary in a certain way with another variable, but can not establish a causal link in that way.

For example, it is possible that having a lot of fun opens someone up to a lot of new experiences (so fun is influencing experience). It is also possible that life experience allows one to enjoy more things as you discover hobbies (so experience is influencing fun). Even a mixture of the two is plausible, or a third variable is in play (maybe rich people have more experience *and* more fun, but fun and experience are not related to each other at all causally).

I think typically, without resorting to making several probably fairly complicated assumptions about how you think the variables interact, establishing causality would require either an experimental design (or if this is not possible, a quasi-experimental design). A correlational study can't give you this type of information, which is pretty much why we have to run a lot of experiments rather than just mining for correlations everywhere.

Comment: If we want to investigate if fun has an effect on experience and initially propose the directional arrow as such: fun ----> experience, what kind of tests need to be run? The dataset of the two continuous variables are "fun" and "experience"

Comment: Establishing causality is quite difficult. As Keith pointed out above, if you have time-series data you can try Granger causality. I don't know much about this method, but it seems straightforward enough on the linked Wikipedia page. More conventionally, you would either use an evidence-backed scientific theory to argue why fun ---> experience is likely (though some would argue there are epistemic issues with this, and I would agree) or run an experimental design, which would require gathering data again. I don't think it can be done without new data or assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that *you can't use Pearson correlation to determine causality*. This is directly related to the popular saying that causation means correlation, but not vise versa.

To give a reason, I think it's best to look at Wilk's lambda as a test of significance. Briefly, Wilk's lambda can be used as a significance test for the correlation between two multivariate random vectors. Let's say you have two random vectors $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$, each containing features that quantify "fun" and "experience", respectively. The question is whether we can regress $\bf X$ given $\bf Y$. To address this, there are several multivariate tests that can be used that measure the "association" or relationship between the two random vectors $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$ [(Kshisargar 1972)](https://books.google.com.au/books/about/Multivariate_Analysis.html?id=l8q2PQAACAAJ&redir_esc=y). Wilk's test (which is known as Wilk's lambda) is proportional to

$\Lambda \propto \prod_{i=1}^p (1-r_i^2) $

is fully determined by the correlation coefficients between $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$, where $r_i$ are the sample correlation coefficients between the vectors $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$. The sample correlation coefficients can be calculated using canonical correlation analysis given an equal number of observations from $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$. The distribution of $\Lambda$ determines how likely it is that $\bf Y$ can be used to regress $\bf X$. Alternatively, had we selected to use $\bf X$ as the regressor, $\Lambda$ would have been the same, since the sample correlation coefficients (and the correlation coefficients) are symmetric with respect to $\bf X$ and $\bf Y$. Therefore, however certain you are that $\bf X$ can cause $\bf Y$ (as far as correlation is concerned), you're equally certain that $\bf Y$ can cause $\bf X$.

Answer (score 1):

You always have to remember that correlation is not causality! No correlation coefficient will tell you the causal relationship of your variables. The only way you can identify causation might be to run linear regression with lagged variables (if you have time series data) and see what seems to predict the other based on time. Otherwise only logical reasoning will help.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_does_not_imply_causation